# Artifactory OSS: LDAP authentication timeout errors

Tags: artifactory

I am installing Artifactory OSS at my company. All worked very well during our tests, but in production we often receive LDAP authentication errors. Details below:

- OS: CentOS 7
- Docker 1.10.1
- Artifactory version: OSS 4.12.0.1 in Docker container

Problem:

Several times per day Artifactory OSS stops authenticating users with LDAP. At the same time, other services in neighbor containers continue operating properly with the same LDAP server. User authentication is very rare, only for release rolling.

We found only one workaround: - restarting the Artifactory container.

The error that appears in the logs during the problem is:

```
2016-09-22 09:34:55,698 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [ERROR] (o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:70) - Error connecting to the LDAP server:
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:60000ms.; remaining name '/'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:217) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:809) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:792) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:251) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.NewFilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(NewFilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:89) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryBindAuthenticator.authenticate(ArtifactoryBindAuthenticator.java:141) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.LdapServiceImpl.testLdapConnection(LdapServiceImpl.java:75) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.testLdapConnection(SecurityServiceImpl.java:2275) [artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.testLdapConnection(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.security.ldap.ldapsettings.TestLdapSettingsService.testLdapConnection(TestLdapSettingsService.java:76) [artifactory-rest-ui-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.security.ldap.ldapsettings.TestLdapSettingsService.execute(TestLdapSettingsService.java:63) [artifactory-rest-ui-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:38) [artifactory-rest-common-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:92) [artifactory-rest-common-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.admin.security.ldap.LdapSettingResource.testLdapSetting(LdapSettingResource.java:96) [artifactory-rest-ui-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:200) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:91) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:391) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:206) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:160) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:61) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:111) [artifactory-web-application-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:60000ms.
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:490) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:638) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:561) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1985) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1844) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1786) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:396) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:297) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:59) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate$3.executeWithContext(NewSpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:253) ~[artifactory-core-4.12.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:806) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
2016-09-22 09:34:55,700 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [ERROR] (o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:71) - Error connecting to the LDAP server:
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to mention that in order to improve the search performance, your Artifactory LDAP 'Search Base' field should be narrow as possible and point to a specific area that includes all of your requirements (users, groups...), but still not force Artifactory to search over the entire tree (which can be pretty heavy).
With regards to the timeout, you can increase the default timeout value by modifying the 'artifactory.security.ldap.socket.timeoutMillis' flag in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties file.
You might also find the pool timeout useful as well (artifactory.security.ldap.pool.timeoutMillis) to timeout idle connections and clean stale connections.